# update manager doesnt work

Tags: updates

My update manager doesn't work and comes up with this:

```
please check your internet connection
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

but my internet connection is fine please help.

Comment: ive even plugged in my laptop in to a ethernet port

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you get a PPA error message like that, it means the developer's package you want is not available for your specific version of Ubuntu.

Looking in the "java" directory of the PPA link your package manager failed to find, we see:

[image: The distribution directory of the "java" archive]

It looks like ferramroberto does not offer a quantal version of this package yet.